# i want to pull data from webpage but at last i am unable to write data in sheet. Data is in table form (multiple row,col)?

Tags: excel, vba

unable to pull data from the webpage & also a problem to write data in the sheet.

Sub pulldata()

'declaration

```
Dim IE As Object
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
```

'start application

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
```

'navigation

```
IE.navigate "https://nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?segmentLink=17&instrument=OPTIDX&symbol=NIFTY&date=25APR2019"
```

'loop until load page

```
Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop
```

'put data in webpage and click on submit

```
Set doc = IE.document

doc.getElementById("underlyStock").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("URLList").Range("A2").Value
doc.parentWindow.execScript "goBtnClick('stock');", "javascript"
```

'loop until load page

```
Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop
```

'pull data from elementid- "octable" to sheet- "nse"

```
strVal = doc.getElementById("octable").innerText
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("nse").Range("A1").Offset(r, 0).Value = strVal
r = r + 1
```

End Sub

I want table data in nse sheet (Sheet name).

Comment: Have you looked at similar questions on here and they have some examples of working code...

Comment: Sir,I try but didn't get the right answer.

Comment: Whatever answers you find will need editing to match your situation - don’t expect them to have written for your needs...

Comment: Can you provide an example underlying stock value please? Whatever ThisWorkbook.Sheets("URLList").Range("A2").Value  is . Page doesn't seem to return anything for items from this list: https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/derivatives/equities/fo_underlying_home.htm

Comment: @QHarr, The underlying stocks in the linked page is OK but may be server is not working fully outside trading hour (usual).

Comment: @AhmedAU Thanks. I hadn't noticed the top line of your answer

Comment: @user3624187, a suggestion outside the scope of SO. I frequently found NSE sever not fully functional outside trading hours. So for the purpose of Option chain data fetching outside trading hours, may please explore feasibility to process latest historic FO data provided by [NSE](https://www.nseindia.com/content/fo/fo.zip) as an alternative. This Zip contains 2 CSV file (Option & Fut). This file may be downloaded processed by VBA to get the required underlying & strike-price option chains etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May try something like this,  I only tried successfully with Nifty Data Only as i don't know underlying symbols except "SBIN" for SBI and it also giving page "Internal Server Error - Read" even in manual surfing (may be due to it is Sunday).

May try with your underlying symbols (may be at appropriate time)

Code:

```
Sub pulldata()
'declaration
Dim IE As Object
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
'start application
Dim Tbl As HTMLTable, Cel As HTMLTableCell, Rw As HTMLTableRow, Col As HTMLTableCol
Dim TrgRw As Long, TrgCol As Long



Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
'navigation

IE.navigate "https://nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?segmentLink=17&instrument=OPTIDX&symbol=NIFTY&date=25APR2019"
'loop until load page

Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop
'put data in webpage and click on submit

Set doc = IE.document

'doc.getElementById("underlyStock").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("URLList").Range("A2").Value
'doc.parentWindow.execScript "goBtnClick('stock');", "javascript"
'loop until load page

Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop
'pull data from elementid- "octable" to sheet- "nse"

Set Tbl = doc.getElementById("octable")


TrgRw = 1
    For Each Rw In Tbl.Rows
    TrgCol = 1
        For Each Cel In Rw.Cells
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("nse").Cells(TrgRw, TrgCol).Value = Cel.innerText
        TrgCol = TrgCol + Cel.colSpan   ' if Column span is > 1 multiple
        Next Cel
    TrgRw = TrgRw + 1
    Next Rw
End Sub
```

Comment: Ahmed AU sir thank you very much, the code is working very fine.

Comment: Sir can you please help me in this vba- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55749967/vba-loop-to-next-url-after-15-20-url-it-start-overriding-data-in-same-cell-why

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem as @AhmedAU mentioned regarding internal server errors.

If this resolves consider using the inbuilt data from web tools. Tools > Data > From Web > add in url to the address bar that includes your symbol e.g.

https://nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?segmentLink=17&instrument=OPTIDX&symbol=ACC&date=25APR2019

Press GO. Leave for a moment then select the table you want and import. The table will be imported into Excel.

In earlier versions of Excel you may need to download the free powerquery add-in from Microsoft and use the Powerquery tab to perform the same tasks.