# VBA loop to next url after 15-20 url it start overriding data in same cell. Why it start putting data on wrong cell after some url?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get data from url & loop to next and put in next empty column. all working fine but after some URLs start overriding data in seme cell.

```
Sub pulldata()

    Dim tod As String
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument

    Dim Tbl As HTMLTable, Cel As HTMLTableCell, Rw As HTMLTableRow, Col As HTMLTableCol
    Dim TrgRw As Long, TrgCol As Long

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True

    IE.navigate "https://nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?segmentLink=17&instrument=OPTIDX&symbol=NIFTY&date=25APR2019"

    Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    tod = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("URLList").Range("C2").Value
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

    ActiveSheet.Name = tod

    Set doc = IE.document

    For nurl = 2 To 191
        lCol = Range("IV2").End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 0).Column

        doc.getElementById("underlyStock").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("URLList").Range("A" & nurl).Value
        doc.parentWindow.execScript "goBtnClick('stock');", "javascript"

        Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
            Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
        Loop

        strVal = Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 0).Select
        Set Tbl = doc.getElementById("octable")

        TrgRw = 1
        For Each Rw In Tbl.Rows
            TrgCol = 1
            For Each Cel In Rw.Cells
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets(tod).Cells(1, lCol).Cells(TrgRw, TrgCol).Value = Cel.innerText
                TrgCol = TrgCol + Cel.colSpan   ' if Column span is > 1 multiple
            Next Cel
            TrgRw = TrgRw + 1
        Next Rw
    Next
End Sub
```

Why VBA start overriding after 15-20 urls.

Comment: You may want to move `TrgRw = 1` outside the first `For loop`. Outside the `For nurl = 2 To 191`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is better option to collect Data of each underlying Vertically one below  anther. Trying to ascertain column counts  from last data may not produce correct result all time in some cases (like Derivative ban etc) table may be empty. Otherwise a fixed column size is to be take for horizontally data store.

In my test data will be shown as below
[image]

Code:

```
Sub pulldata2()
    Dim tod As String, UnderLay As String
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument

    Dim Tbl As HTMLTable, Cel As HTMLTableCell, Rw As HTMLTableRow, Col As HTMLTableCol
    Dim TrgRw As Long, TrgCol As Long


    tod = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("URLList").Range("C2").Value   'C2 must have proper sheet name
    have = False
    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If sht.Name = tod Then
        have = True
        Exit For
        End If
    Next sht

    If have = False Then
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = tod
    Else
    If MsgBox("Sheet " & tod & " already exists Overwrite Data?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    End If


    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "https://nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?segmentLink=17&instrument=OPTIDX&symbol=NIFTY&date=25APR2019"

        Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
        Loop

    Set doc = IE.document

    TrgRw = 1
    For Nurl = 2 To 191

        UnderLay = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("URLList").Range("A" & Nurl).Value
        doc.getElementById("underlyStock").Value = UnderLay
        doc.parentWindow.execScript "goBtnClick('stock');", "javascript"

        Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
            Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
        Loop

        'strVal = Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 0).Select
        Set Tbl = doc.getElementById("octable")

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(tod).Cells(TrgRw, 1).Value = UnderLay  'keep as per your requirement
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(tod).Cells(TrgRw, 1).Font.Size = 20
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(tod).Cells(TrgRw, 1).Font.Bold = True
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(tod).Cells(TrgRw, 1).Select
        TrgRw = TrgRw + 1


        For Each Rw In Tbl.Rows
            TrgCol = 1
            For Each Cel In Rw.Cells
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets(tod).Cells(TrgRw, TrgCol).Value = Cel.innerText
                TrgCol = TrgCol + Cel.colSpan   ' if Column span is > 1 multiple
            Next Cel
            TrgRw = TrgRw + 1
        Next Rw

    TrgRw = TrgRw + 1
    Next Nurl
End Sub
```

EDIT: if Horizontal target is preferred my modify last section of the code like this:

```
Set doc = IE.document

Dim ColOff As Long

For Nurl = 2 To 191
ColOff = (Nurl - 2) * 26
TrgRw = 1
    UnderLay = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("URLList").Range("A" & Nurl).Value
    doc.getElementById("underlyStock").Value = UnderLay
    doc.parentWindow.execScript "goBtnClick('stock');", "javascript"

    Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    'strVal = Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 0).Select
    Set Tbl = doc.getElementById("octable")

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(tod).Cells(TrgRw, ColOff + 1).Value = UnderLay
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(tod).Cells(TrgRw, ColOff + 1).Font.Size = 20
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(tod).Cells(TrgRw, ColOff + 1).Font.Bold = True
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(tod).Cells(TrgRw, ColOff + 1).Select
    TrgRw = TrgRw + 1


    For Each Rw In Tbl.Rows
        TrgCol = 1
        For Each Cel In Rw.Cells
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(tod).Cells(TrgRw, ColOff + TrgCol).Value = Cel.innerText
            TrgCol = TrgCol + Cel.colSpan   ' if Column span is > 1 multiple
        Next Cel
        TrgRw = TrgRw + 1
    Next Rw

TrgRw = TrgRw + 1
Next Nurl
```

Comment: Words are not enough, Working excellent. @Ahmed AU sir thank you very much. Only  few great personalities can help like you sir, Once again thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

I made some small untested changes. Try it out but it should work.

```
Sub pulldata()
    Dim tod As String
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument
    Dim Tbl As HTMLTable, Cel As HTMLTableCell, Rw As HTMLTableRow, Col As HTMLTableCol
    Dim TrgRw As Long, TrgCol As Long
    Dim wk As Workbook
    Set wk = ThisWrokbook
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "https://nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?segmentLink=17&instrument=OPTIDX&symbol=NIFTY&date=25APR2019"

    Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    tod = wk.Sheets("URLList").Range("C2").Value
    wk.Sheets.Add After:=wk.Sheets(wk.Sheets.Count)
    wk.Worksheets(wk.Sheets.Count).Name = tod
    Set doc = IE.document
    TrgRw = 1

    For nurl = 2 To 191
        lCol = wk.Sheets(tod).Range("IV2").End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 0).Column
        doc.getElementById("underlyStock").Value = wk.Sheets("URLList").Range("A" & nurl).Value
        doc.parentWindow.execScript "goBtnClick('stock');", "javascript"

        Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
            Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
        Loop

        strVal = wk.Sheets(tod).Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 0).Select
        Set Tbl = doc.getElementById("octable")

        For Each Rw In Tbl.Rows
            TrgCol = 1
            For Each Cel In Rw.Cells
                wk.Sheets(tod).Cells(TrgRw, TrgCol).Value = Cel.innerText
                TrgCol = TrgCol + Cel.colSpan   ' if Column span is > 1 multiple
            Next Cel
            TrgRw = TrgRw + 1
        Next Rw
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: It gets only 1st URL data, even loop to next URL but not writing data in the sheet.

Comment: Does it stop after getting to the second URL, or does it continue to the next one without adding any data after the first?

Comment: it continue to the next one without adding any data after the first.

Comment: Try it now, I think the error was on the last for loop to begin with. This is your original line: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(tod).Cells(1, lCol).Cells(TrgRw, TrgCol).Value = Cel.innerText` There are two Cells.Cells nested. Lets see if it works.

Comment: Sir if we do this, then we are unable to put data on next empty colum. Now it start overriding data on starting cell.

Comment: What you meant to use is Cells.Offset, not Cells.Cells, which is why it is probably not doing it properly. `.Sheets(tod).Cells(1, lCol).Offset(TrgRw, TrgCol).Value`